# Cant align image to center horizontally

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to position my image to the center horizontally, but I can't seem to make it work, this is what I have.

```
    .drugimg p img {
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    border: 3px solid #73ad21;
    padding: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: What element is `drugimg`? Do you have some styling for that element? When you say you want to position your image in center horizontally, you mean horizontally in relation to what?

Comment: if you want to center the image you need to put the text-align in the parent element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margins and absolute positioning generally don't mix.

If you want to center horizontally you can either do this (relative positioning):

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Or this (absolute positioning):

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

For the second solution, keep in mind that it will be centered horizontally relative to the nearest parent element with `position:relative`. This means that if the immediate parent is relatively positioned, the child will be horizontally centered relative to it. If the parent's parent is relatively positioned, the element will be centered relative to that. If *nothing* is relatively positioned, your element will be centered relative to the viewport.